# RXJs Switch Map flow and API cancellation

Tags: angular, api, http, rxjs, switchmap

I am working on an existing Angular application and there is an issue where the APIs keep getting cancelled sometimes. It is mostly happening on Development site but not on local.

```
somefunctionName(x) {
this.service.serviceFunction(x.id, x.otherId).subscribe(_ => {
    -- do something --
  });
}

<- Service File -> 
serviceFunction(id?: number, otherId?: number): Observable<void> {
return this.http.post<context>(`url`, { id, otherId })
  .pipe(
    tap(y => {
      this.someFunction(y);
      this._variable.next();
    }),
    switchMap(() => this.targetFunction())
  );
}

private targetFunction(): Observable<any> {
return forkJoin([
  this.firstAPICall(),
  this.secondAPICall(),
  this.thirdAPICall(),
  this.fourthAPICall()
]);
}
```

I have a function 'someFunctionName' which is calling the serviceFunction and uses SwitchMap to call targetFunction. The APIs inside the target function are getting cancelled. I have never worked with switchMap but I have basic understanding about it. Could someone please explain the flow and some pointers on why the API are getting cancelled?

**EDIT:**
*Please find below the steps executed to debug the issue:*

Console and Session Storage Testing – Adding console logs and stored various requests hitting the interceptor but none of them went into error exception when the APIs are getting cancelled.

Checked the possibility of unsubscribed observable emitting any values while the APIs are running as it might be causing some conflict, so I moved the route to another screen at the end when all the four APIs inside the fork Join are executed but it did not work.

Cancelling of APIs could have happened because of SwitchMap but this had lesser probability since SwitchMap only cancels if the outer observable is called again but that was not happening still to rule this out, I replaced SwitchMap with MergeMap but the APIs were still getting cancelled. (Thanks to Chris in the comments for detailed explanation regarding SwitchMap)

Added catchError at the end of ForkJoin and at the end of all 4 APIs which are getting cancelled but the flow did not go into catch block.

Tried executing each of the APIs individually using POSTMAN and all were successful. I am trying to run them in parallel too using POSTMAN to check if the error is happening during parallel execution.

On the Dev site, while pausing on exceptions I did find an error Array.Prototype.ForEach called on Null or undefined but it happened once when the APIs did not cancel so I do not think the issues are related.

Comment: Can you please explain further, what exactly is failing?

Comment: It happens sometimes, when the APIs inside the target function are called, they all get cancelled. I tried debugging a lot and since it is not happening on Local environment and only on Dev Site, it is difficult to catch the exact cause of cancellation. I am trying to understand the flow of the code and reasons because of which the APIs are getting cancelled. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: is there `takeUntil` before subscribe in `this.service.serviceFunction` call?

Comment: Hi @vitaliykotov . Yes. The complete code is `this.service.serviceFunction().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribed)).subscribe`

Comment: @SahilManaktala could you pls confirm that all 4 request inside the `forkJoin` are getting cancelled? Cause maybe one of them is erroring and therefore triggering the unsub of the other three.

Comment: @akotech Yes, all 4 are getting cancelled. If there was a bug in the API call it should have affected my local environment too so I thought it might be related to SwitchMap as it intends to cancel out previously running calls if the outer observable is subscribed again but I am not able to reproduce it.

Comment: @akotech Also, it does not happen every time. Mostly it cancels out on the first instance and when I refresh the page, the APIs run without any issues.

Comment: you can add a catchError operator to debug, i suspect it is due to one of the failing call in forkjoin

Comment: `switchMap` only cancels if it has received another value, in which case it would call `this.targetFunction` again. However, this is an impossible case since http post only returns a single value. Therefore, this has nothing to do with `switchMap`, it is simply one of your api calls failing at the development site. If any of those calls throw an error, forkJoin will error as well and all other observables will be immediately unsubscribed.

Comment: Have you checked that `this.unsubscribed` doesn't emit any value while you're making requests?

Comment: @FanCheung I have an interceptor file catching every HTTP request being made and their corresponding errors. It never enters the error part. Also tried using catchError for the particular APIs but again, no error is being logged.

Comment: @vitaliykotov All subscriptions are unsubscribed once we move away from the particular screen. In this case, routing does not take place until all those 4 APIs are completed.

Answer (score 0):

I need context for when *someFunctionName* function is called, because switchMap will **complete** inner observable if there is a new emit from outer observable (in this case is this.http.post(`url`, { id, otherId })). Maybe you accidentally called someFunctionName() multiple times? You can check the network tab.

Comment: Hi. On my local, I added a debug point and confirmed that the function is only being called once.